# cmbright with Xelatex and lyx

Tags: xetex, lyx

Is it possible to use cmbright with xelatex for both math and text?

The way to use it in the text is here

[Use cmbright with unicode text under XeLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144449/use-cmbright-with-unicode-text-under-xelatex)

But the math still appear in usual latin form. COuld you help me?

Fabien

Comment: Did you try adding `\usepackage{cmbright}` before `\usepackage{fontspec}`?

Comment: That's the problem! Lyx insert \usepackage{fontspec} before the preambule...

Comment: Anyway for non-Lyx users, I've exported my lyx document to latex and switched the ordering of the two packages and it works pefectly

Comment: One of the reason I don't recommend using LyX is because it does what its programmers want, not what *the user* wants.

Comment: Ok, better not to start this discussion  :) Thanks anyway